# Ruby Regex for date and time

Tags: ruby

I am reading a log file and matching a pattern in the file; and if it matches do the regex on the line.

```
f = File.open(file,"r")
f.seek(0,IO::SEEK_END)

while true do
  select([f])
  line = f.gets
  if line =~ pattern
    a = line.sub(/ .*$/, "")
```

I have tried the above method and it fails for some reason.

So I have

> "2017053007:00:02 : INFO : Processing bucket : East3"

coming into the line after matching the pattern. Just need to get this "2017053007:00:02" filtered out using the regex.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Just get a list of all timestamps, like `2017053007:00:02`, in the file? It looks like you've seriously over-complicated the implementation.

Comment: I just copy pasted this and it is working `"2017053007:00:02 : INFO : Processing bucket : East3".sub(/ .*$/, "")`

Comment: You can't "**do** the regex". Although, you can "**use** a regex".

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
input = "2017053007:00:02 : INFO : Processing bucket : East3"
input[/(?<=\A\d{10}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s:\s).*/]
#⇒ "INFO : Processing bucket : East3"

input[/\S+/]
#⇒ "2017053007:00:02"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try : 
([0-9]+:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})

Answer (score 0):

without **REGEX**:

```
> a = "2017053007:00:02 : INFO : Processing bucket : East3"
> a.split.first
#=> "2017053007:00:02"
```